# Wix Patches and using '*' instead of Component Guids

Tags: wix, guid, patch

While searching for best practices, I came across [this thread](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Best-Practices-Using-quot-quot-for-GUID-automation-td5234716.html), which is discussing the use of '*' instead of GUIDs in components. Also I read similar discussion on different forums related to same topic

As far I know, while generating GUID dynamically from '*', if the destination of a Component is changed, so its GUID would also be changed. There might be some other factors as well.

Let's say we released ver 1.0.0.0 and then in 1.0.1.0 we changed the destination of a Component from Dir1 to Dir2.

**Question:** If we generate Differential Patch between these two versions, would the file get patched who's destination was changed in ver 1.0.1.0? Would using '*' in this case would be good?

Regards
Farrukh

Answer (score 1):

You can't move a file in a patch: That ends up being a removal of the component from the old location and an addition of a "new" component in the new location. You cannot remove components in a patch.

Comment: Thanks Bob. That means, if GUID changed between these two builds due to change of location, it would be considered as removal of Component. So using "*" instead of GUIDs in this case is not reliable.

Comment: You can't move a file in a patch, regardless of how you generate the component GUID. Moving a file without changing its component GUID will also fail.

Comment: My results are different. Using * didn't patched the file. Using GUID, however, patched the file, but didn't moved. Here is scenario:
In v1.msi, File1.txt and File2.txt are installed in C:\TestDir. In v2.msi, I changed the location and contents of File2.txt to C:\NewTestdir. I generated patch "Using Patch Creation Properties" method. When applied, the contents of File2.txt changed to the one packed in v2.msi, but it didn't changed the location. I can share the project files if you wish to try.

Comment: Right, like I said, you can't move the file.